# Need to parse a text file line by line with a certain search string using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to parse a text file line by line with a certain search string and if that string is not found in any line, then code should output that entire line to separate text file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service; in order to better help answer your question, we prefer that your question demonstrate that you've tried to solve your problem yourself, with specific examples (usually code snippets) of what you've tried, and details of what problems and errors you've run into. Please consider editing your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use select-string:

```
Select-String -Path "yourfile.txt" -Pattern "yourstring" -NotMatch | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line | Out-File "output.txt"
```